# How to restore the pre-17.10 behaviour of gnome-calculator: opening multiple instances by middle-clicking in the Ubuntu dock?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, multiple-instances, gnome-calculator

In ubuntu 17.04 and earlier, a middle-click on the calculator icon in the launcher would start another instance of it, like it still does for most other programs. This does no longer work in 17.10/18.04 - how can I restore the old behavior?

(I know that I can open a terminal and type gnome-calculator but that is too cumbersome)